# numpy too many indices for array error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy object with the following format:

```
date,column1,column2,column3,column4,,column5,,column6,,column7,,column8,,column9,,column10
date,column1,column2,column3,column4,,column5,,column6,,column7,,column8,,column9,,column10
date,column1,column2,column3,column4,,column5,,column6,,column7,,column8,,column9,,column10
...
```

I am attempting to retrieve only rows that meet a certain date condition such as all rows where the date is greater than 2005 as follows (myData is a numpy object):

```
li = (myData[:,0] >  myData[2][0].year)
```

however i keep getting the following error:

`too many indices for array,`

the shape is (128,)
dtype is [('Date', 'O'), ('SF1.AAPL_DEBT_MRQ - Value', '

can someone please advise, thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't told us enough to go on. The code posted here is perfectly functional for a 2-d array. (This performs the same operation in a bare-bones manner and it works fine: `a = numpy.arange(15).reshape(5, 3); li = a[:,0] > a[2][0]; a[li]`.)

Comment: what's the shape and dtype of this 'object'?

Comment: shape = (128,)  type = [('Date', 'O'), ('SF1.AAPL_DEBT_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_EQUITY_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_NETINC_MRY - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_BVPS_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_FCF_MRY - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_EPS_MRY - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_CURRENTRATIO_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_DIVYIELD - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_ASSETSC_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_LIABILITIES_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_PRICE - ', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_LIABILITIESC_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_REVENUE_MRY - Value', '<f8'), ('SF1.AAPL_PE1_MRT - Value', '<f8')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was built upon the answer of @hpaulj, the missing step I've added  is converting the list of booleans to a `ndarray`

```
% cat puff.csv
date,pippo,pluto,paperino
2012-10-20,3.,5.,6.
2013-05-22,4.,6.,2.
2013-07-31,5.,1.,6.
2014-10-08,0.,3.,4.
% ipython
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 18 2014, 12:50:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l = np.genfromtxt('puff.csv', dtype=None,  delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

In [3]: print l
[('2012-10-20', 3.0, 5.0, 6.0) ('2013-05-22', 4.0, 6.0, 2.0)
 ('2013-07-31', 5.0, 1.0, 6.0) ('2014-10-08', 0.0, 3.0, 4.0)]

In [4]: l[np.array([x[0][:4]<'2014' for x in l])]
Out[4]: 
array([('2012-10-20', 3.0, 5.0, 6.0), ('2013-05-22', 4.0, 6.0, 2.0),
       ('2013-07-31', 5.0, 1.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])

In [5]: print l[np.array([x[0][:4]<'2014' for x in l])]
[('2012-10-20', 3.0, 5.0, 6.0) ('2013-05-22', 4.0, 6.0, 2.0)
 ('2013-07-31', 5.0, 1.0, 6.0)]

In [6]:
```

Comment: thanks for the response, when i try doing something similar i get the following message: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Well, we're closing on target! you can get the year (or whatever) from a `datetime.datetime` object using a member notation.   If my `x[0]` above, in the list comprehension, were a datetime I would had written`x[0].year < 2014` (note that it's an integer comparison!). Can you please test that in your code?

Comment: yup i did that just 30 mins ago and it was working! Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Or read the same references... OK, glad to have been helpful, ciao

Comment: just a little debugging on what you did plus reading a little documentation, grazi ciao!

Comment: If you can get `genfromtxt` to load the date as a `np.datetime64` type, you can do the testing without a Python comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a structured array, most likely created by reading data from a `csv` (with `np.genfromtxt`).  If so it probably is 1 dimensional with a complex `dtype`.  Assuming the first field is called 'Date', then you can get an array of all the dates with

```
myData['Date']
```

The data for the 1st row will be

```
myData[0]
```

The 1st date will either be `myData[0]['Date']` or `myData['Date'][0]`.

---

As I guessed, this is a 1d structured array:

```
shape = (128,)
type = [('Date', 'O'), ('SF1.AAPL_DEBT_MRQ - Value', '<f8'), ....)]
```

The `'O'` indictates the date is an object, which could be anything, so I can't say anything about its format or content.

Try:

```
li = [date.year>2005 for date in myData['Date']
```

This should at least get the indexing right.  I'm guessing that each 'date' has a 'year' attribute that can be compared to '2005'.  This should give a list 128 long of True/False.

Try using:

```
myData[li]
```

to get just the rows that meet your criteria.  You may have to convert `li` to an array, or list of index numbers.  But regardless, `myData` will always be indexed with one value or list.  The `too many indices` error means you are treating it like a 2d array when it is actually just 1d.

---

gboffi's data can be read, with field names, as

```
data = np.genfromtxt('puff.csv', dtype=None,  delimiter=',', names=True)
```

with the resulting `dtype`

```
dtype([('date', 'S10'), ('pippo', '<f8'), ('pluto', '<f8'), ('paperino', '<f8')])
```

The desired rows can be found with:

```
I=[x[:4]<'2014' for x in data['date']]
# the 'date' field can be selected before or after element selection
# [True, True, True, False]
data[np.array(I)]
```

`numpy` has a `datetime64` type that can be used for comparisons:

```
dates=[np.datetime64(x) for x in data['date']]
I = dates<np.datetime64('2014-01-01')
# array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
data[I]
```

---

If the date format is correct, `genfromtxt` can do the string to date conversion:

```
In [206]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=('datetime64[D]','f8','f8','f8'),  delimiter=',', names=True)
In [207]: data
Out[207]: 
array([(datetime.date(2012, 10, 20), 3.0, 5.0, 6.0),
       (datetime.date(2013, 5, 22), 4.0, 6.0, 2.0),
       (datetime.date(2013, 7, 31), 5.0, 1.0, 6.0),
       (datetime.date(2014, 10, 8), 0.0, 3.0, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[D]'), ('pippo', '<f8'), ('pluto', '<f8'), ('paperino', '<f8')])
```

And the year selection can be done with:

```
In [208]: data[data['date']<np.datetime64('2014','Y')]
Out[208]: 
array([(datetime.date(2012, 10, 20), 3.0, 5.0, 6.0),
       (datetime.date(2013, 5, 22), 4.0, 6.0, 2.0),
       (datetime.date(2013, 7, 31), 5.0, 1.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[D]'), ('pippo', '<f8'), ('pluto', '<f8'), ('paperino', '<f8')])
```

Or even a date selection:

```
In [209]: data[data['date']<np.datetime64('2013-06-01','D')]
Out[209]: 
array([(datetime.date(2012, 10, 20), 3.0, 5.0, 6.0),
       (datetime.date(2013, 5, 22), 4.0, 6.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[D]'), ('pippo', '<f8'), ('pluto', '<f8'), ('paperino', '<f8')])
```

Comment: i can get access to the date, what i want is to filter out fields of a particular date and process the structure from there onwards. Dtype is specified above

Comment: it is a date object for sure, but that is not really answering the question as to getting filtered rows of a particular date only

Comment: that was closer, but when i tried print myData[li,:] following your suggestion i still got this message: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/records.py:458: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index
  obj = ndarray.__getitem__(self, indx)
too many indices for array

Comment: Don't access `myData` with 2 indices.  `myData[li]` should be the correct way to use a boolean indexing list.

Comment: getting closer, however when i do something like  li = [date.year ==  2005 for date in myData['Date']] i get the same row outputted many times over (datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 30, 0, 0), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.61142857, nan, nan, nan)]

Comment: @hpaulj I used your suggestion `li = [test(x) for x in arr] ; print arr[li]` using a mock-up array as given by `np.genfromtxt`, but to my greatest surprise I saw that I was choosing either the element `arr[0]` or the element `arr[1]` depending on 'li[n]` being `False` or `True`.  The other puzzling fact was finding that `type(arr[0])` -> `numpy.void`,  what does that `numpy.void ` mean? Thank you